# Change port forwarding to switch instead of modem

Tags: switch

I have an ISP modem connected to a 24-port switch. Can I have the modem pass on port forwarding to the switch instead of it being done by the modem? How is this done? DMZ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Port forwarding is done by the device doing the NAT. It is unlikely that a switch will do NAT.

---

It seems rather foolish to not have a firewall between your ISP and your network (switch). This puts your business at risk. You should have a firewall, and you can NAT on the firewall if you like, then you could forward ports there.